# How to format selection with eslint

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

I found out that if I write in my `settings.json` that:

```json
  "eslint.format.enable": true,
  "[javascriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint",
  }
```

Then I can format the whole page using `ALT + SHIFT + F` with ESLint (or right click -> Format Document).

I can also see once I right click -> `Format Selection With....` then I can see ESLint as an option.

But if I select a line and press right click, then `Format Selection With...` I can't find the Eslint option. (or as a shortcut `CTRL+K`)

So how can I format selection with ESLint?

Comment: Hi, did you figure it out?

Comment: @ShocKwav3_ check that out: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/13835